# MySQL How to select records with indrect IDs?

Tags: mysql, select

My table has a columns labeled `primary_key` and `summary_id`.  The value in the second field `summary_id` in each record maps to the `primary_key` field of another record.  There is a third field `template_id`.  I need to select those records for which:

1. `template_id` is a certain value. Let's say 4.
2. `primary_key` matches at least one of the records' `summary_id` field.

Please don't tell me to redesign the tables.  My next project will have a better design, but I don't have time for that now.  I need to do this with one or more queries; the fewer the better.  Ideally, there's some way to do this with one query, but I'm okay if it requires more.

[image]

This is how far I've gotten with my own query.  (I know it's seriously lacking, which is why I need help.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT esjp_content.template_id
FROM esjp_content
INNER JOIN esjp_hw_config ON esjp_content.template_id = esjp_hw_config.proc_id
INNER JOIN esjp_assets ON esjp_hw_config.primary_key = esjp_assets.hw_config_id
WHERE
    esjp_content.summary_id > 0
        AND
    (esjp_assets.asset_label='C001498500' OR esjp_assets.asset_label='H0065' OR esjp_assets.asset_label='L0009');

SELECT
    esjp_content.primary_key, esjp_content.template_id, esjp_content.content, esjp_content.summary_id
FROM
    esjp_content
WHERE
    esjp_content.template_id = 4;
```

I need the records that `summary_id` points to.  For example, if `summary_id` is 90, then I need the record where `primary_key` is 90.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  I don't really get the second condition.

Comment: Note that (except for the VARCHAR), those numbers in parentheses don't mean much.

Comment: So you dont have time to fix your db design neither to make a proper question. But we have to expend our time trying to guess what you need. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I've added my current progress and original data to the original post.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the existence of at least one row where summary_id = your primary key. like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM esjp_content c
WHERE template_id = 4
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM esjp_content c2 WHERE c2.summary_id = c.primary_key)
```

Comment: I think this is going to work. Let me work with it a bit, before selecting as the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can JOIN same table by using both IDs:

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM
    esjp_content t1
INNER JOIN esjp_content t2 ON t1.summary_id = t2.primary_key
WHERE
    t1.template_id = 4
```

Comment: Thanks, but this returns the records where `summary_id` is set.  I need the records that `summary_id` points to.  For example, if `summary_id` is 90, then I need the record where `primary_key` is 90.