# MySQL How to deal with Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, where-clause

I'm trying to write a query where it selects all records from a table where certain complex/nested criteria are met.  The logic in my query I think is correct, but the problem I'm running into is the final subquery (see example) is returning more than 1 row, which is what I would expect/need. So, the problem is, how do I deal with this?  Does MySQL support some kind of looping or set criterion?

```
SELECT c.primary_key
FROM esjp_content c
WHERE template_id = (
    SELECT DISTINCT esjp_content.template_id
    FROM esjp_content
    INNER JOIN esjp_hw_config ON esjp_content.template_id = esjp_hw_config.proc_id
    INNER JOIN esjp_assets ON esjp_hw_config.primary_key = esjp_assets.hw_config_id
    WHERE
        esjp_content.summary_id > 0
            AND
        (esjp_assets.asset_label='C001498500' OR esjp_assets.asset_label='H0065' OR esjp_assets.asset_label='L0009')
    )
        AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM esjp_content c2 WHERE c2.summary_id = c.primary_key)
        AND
    c.primary_key != (
        /* This subquery returns more than 1 result. */
        SELECT esjp_signoffs.content_id
        FROM esjp_signoffs
        INNER JOIN esjp_assets ON esjp_signoffs.asset_id = esjp_assets.primary_key
        WHERE
            esjp_signoffs.user_id=1
                AND
            (esjp_assets.asset_label='C001498500' OR esjp_assets.asset_label='H0065' OR esjp_assets.asset_label='L0009')
    );
```

For additional details on my tables, see this [other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332153/mysql-how-to-select-records-with-indrect-ids) I made earlier today.  (This is an entirely different question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understan correctly  the

```
   c.primary_key != (
    /* This subquery returns more than 1 result. */
    SELECT esjp_signoffs.content_id
    FROM esjp_signoffs
    INNER JOIN esjp_assets ON esjp_signoffs.asset_id = esjp_assets.primary_key
    WHERE
        esjp_signoffs.user_id=1
            AND
        (esjp_assets.asset_label='C001498500' OR esjp_assets.asset_label='H0065' OR esjp_assets.asset_label='L0009')
);
```

return more then a row .. you could use not  in ..

```
  c.primary_key not in (
```

or

```
 inner join  (  ..... ) t on c.primary_key != t.the_column_you_need
```